# Simulating a Reaction-Diffusion Model - Matlab/Python

Tags: particle-physics, simulations, diffusion

I think Matlab will be the most effective for this (And it's what I'm best at working with but Python help would work too!).

I need to have two sets of particles, lets call them A and B, with a flux Fa and Fb. They enter a grid of length L.

I need to simulate the movement of each of these particles along the grid with the following probabilities:
Movement Right - D
Movement Left - D
Stay in the same spot: 1-2D

Once I have that I can then use the following reactions to simulate what happens when two particles occupy the same space:

A+B=Annihilate prob 1-p
A+B=B prob p(1+m/2)
A+B=A prob p(1+m/2)

where m is some Bias parameter.

I can't figure out how to get Matlab to simulate a constant or inconstant influx of particles into the grid space and then the movements. I can get simulate the brownian motion of two particles, but not sure how I can use the above probabilities.

Any help at all would be mega appreciated.

Even if I could just get a start I maybe able to work it through.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by  " inconstant influx of particles into the grid space " do you want to generate new particles in your grid? In how far is the movement of the particles different than the brownian motion, which you say you know how to do. The reaction thing which is left seems to be just an If statement which is checking if there are As and Bs at the same position and then with a given probability replace them by the product of the reaction. You can include the probability by comparing a random(0,1) number with your reaction probability.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for [scicomp.se] than here.